# Any reason for Android Studio saying HAXM is not installed?

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I am trying to run an Android Emulator in Android Studio, and it says that I need to install HAXM to run it, when I installed it, the message is still there. When I install HAXM, it says:

"Android SDK is up to date.

Running Intel® HAXM installer

Intel HAXM installed successfully!

Done"

But then it still doesn't run the emulator.

For context, I am running Windows 10 on a Mac using Bootcamp. Would that be a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have not tried allready with below way then you can try this way to install HAXM,

restart computer
(1)reboot system
(2) press F10 key
(3)blue window will open for bios setting
(4)select security tab
(3)click on system security
(4)now you will see window on which "Virtualization text" is Disabled on blue popup window
(5)you have to enable it
(6)then save and continue etcc..
(7)you have to install HAXM and run emulator at android studio it will work

hope it will resolved issue.